# Pass by reference to parent PHP class

Tags: php, oop

How can I pass an object by reference to a parent class?

I have the following script, and receive the following error.

> Strict Standards: Declaration of myChild::myMethod() should be
>   compatible with myParent::myMethod($id = NULL, &$model = NULL) in
>   /var/www/bidjunction/html/testing/passbyreference.php on line 19

```
<?php
class myParent
{
    public function myMethod($id=null,&$model=null)
    {
        $model=$model?$model:new stdClass();
        var_dump($model);
    }
}

class myChild extends myParent
{
    public function myMethod($id=null,$model=null)
    {
        $model=new stdClass();
        $model->foo='bar';
        parent::myMethod(123,$model);
    }
}
class myOtherChild extends myParent{}

$myChild=new myChild();
$myChild->myMethod();

$myOtherChild=new myChild();
$myOtherChild->myMethod();
?>
```

Comment: you're passing `$model` by ref in the parent but not the child

Comment: @andrew.  How can it be based by reference by the child?

Comment: Look at the methods signatures and your mistake should be easily spotted

Comment: @PeeHaa.  Meaning that `&$model=null` is not compatible with `$model=null`?

Comment: 1. classes should start with capital letter; 2. objects are always passed by reference since php5, so that would make no sense; 3. due to vanilla naming, your goal is not clear yet smells like bad practice : /

Comment: @moonwave99.  Sorry for naming, just a silly script for me to try to understand what is happening.  Good point!  I forgot all objects are passed by reference!

Comment: @moonwave99 There is still a difference between *passing a variable by reference*, and *passing an object* (by its handle). In this case, it's probably not needed, but consider `function foo(&$x) { $x = new stdClass; }`, which would over-write the *variable*, rather than modifying the passed object. `function foo($x) { $x = new stdClass; }` will simply create a new local variable and leave the passed object untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give some general information about the error. It's thrown because the method parameters are not the same. Your parent class expects a pointer to a reference, while your child expects the instance itself. If you override functions the method name and parameters must be identical.

Change it, so they both expect a pointer:

```
class myParent
{
    public function myMethod($id=null,&$model=null)
    {
    }
}

class myChild extends myParent
{
    public function myMethod($id=null,&$model=null)
    {
    }
}
```

Or they both expect the instance

```
class myParent
{
    public function myMethod($id=null,$model=null)
    {
    }
}

class myChild extends myParent
{
    public function myMethod($id=null,$model=null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to avoid the term "pointer to"; PHP references aren't really pointers in the same way as, say, C (you don't need to explicitly de-reference them), they're more like "aliases", giving the same variable multiple, indistinguishable, names. Clear explanation other than that, though, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

As andrew said in the comment. Your method signatures should be same in both methods according to LISKOV SUBSTITUTION principle when overriding the methods in child or inheriting class.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Could you provide recommendations on how the script should be modified to conform to Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: Just make the two lines that say `public function myMethod($id=null,&$model=null)` identical, rather than one of them missing out the `&`

Answer (score 0):

when you extend a class, you're extending that class type, not an instance of it, if you want the parent to have access to the child you must inject it

```
class myParent
{

   public $child;

   public function addChild($child){
      $this->child = $child;
   }


}

$myParent = new parent();

$myChild=new myChild();

$myParent->addChild($myChild);
```